# No Define call for backbone

Tags: backbone.js, internet-explorer-8, requirejs

I have a backbone + requirejs app.
I am getting this `No Define call for backbone` in IE8

I have enabled enforceDefine for app support in IE8

Require Config file

```
define([], function(){

require.config({
  enforceDefine : true,
  shim: {
  "underscore": {
    deps: [],
    exports: "_"
  },
  "backbone": {
    deps: ["jquery", "underscore"],
    exports: "Backbone"
  },
  ...
  },
  baseUrl : 'scripts/',
  paths: {
    backbone        : '../libs/backbone/backbone',  
    jquery          : '../libs/jquery/dist/jquery',
    underscore      : '../libs/underscore/underscore'
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: As far as i remember there is no need to wrap in `define` require config

Comment: i got an error saying `no define` for config file.

Comment: have u unwraped it from `define([], function(){ ....})` ?

Comment: Yes i had. which had resulted in `no define for config file` Error

Comment: do u use anywhere  `require('config')` or `define(['config'], function...)`

Comment: yes am `define(['config'], function...) `

Comment: there is no need in this. usually config file is loaded as `data-main` with `<script data-main="config" src="require.js">`. You should not mention it as dependencies for any AND modules.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60867/discussion-between-evgeniy-and-anenth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your html file:

```
<doctype!>
<html>
...
<!-- You can load config ahead of require -->
<script type="text/javascript">
require.config({
  enforceDefine : true, // +1 for this in IE 8!!
  shim: {
  "underscore": {
    deps: [],
    exports: "_"
  },
  "backbone": {
    deps: ["jquery", "underscore"],
    exports: "Backbone"
  },
  ...
  },
  baseUrl : 'scripts/',
  paths: {
    backbone        : '../libs/backbone/backbone',  
    jquery          : '../libs/jquery/dist/jquery',
    underscore      : '../libs/underscore/underscore'
  }
 });
</script>
<script data-main="entry-point.js" src="path/to/require.js"></script>
```

In entry-point.js

```
define([deps1, deps2], function(Dep1, Dep2){
...
});
```

Additionally, it is worthwhile to take a look at [various ways to separate config from main](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Patterns-for-separating-config-from-the-main-module)

Comment: thanks i went with https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Patterns-for-separating-config-from-the-main-module#2